# Mapping the values of a RDD to their dictionary values

Tags: java, dictionary, apache-spark

I've this piece of code:

```
List tmp = colRDD.collect();
int ctr = 0;
for(Object o : tmp){
    if (!dictionary.containsKey(o)) {
        dictionary.put(o, ctr++);
    }
}
revDictionary = dictionary.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getValue, c -> c.getKey()));
colRDD = colRDD.map(x ->  {return dictionary.get(x);});
```

At the start, I materialize the RDD and put each value in a hash table where the RDD values are keys.
Then, I sımple want to map each value in the RDD to their dictionary value.
However, I get a `Task not serializable` error. Why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be caused by trying to access a variable scoped to the driver, from within code that is evaluated by an executor.

Given your sample code, the most likely culprit is `dictionary` in this line of code:

```
colRDD = colRDD.map(x ->  {return dictionary.get(x);});
```

However the issue could also be coming from further up in your code than you have supplied here, so you might need to check that too.

The reason for this is because `dictionary` resides in memory of your driver, which is likely running in a separate JVM instance than your executors. The lambda you have passed to `colRDD.map` is evaluated by an executor, not the driver. The function is serialised as the task to be executed, sent to an executor to be run. But the Spark engine is unable to serialise the task because of the 'closure' around `dictionary` and hence, exception.

Comment: I know the error comes from there. Don't undertand why though.

Comment: Added more detail to help understand what is happening.

Comment: @ImDarrenG Answer is correct, however it would be good to use broadcast to not send dictionary every time map is called

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work because the dictionary is being modified in the example. OP asked another question on SO for how to approach the problem where I have suggested an approach in a comment, but I don't Java so have a look if you haven't already :)

Comment: OP must have deleted the other question sorry